# react router dom display nothing blank page showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I remove the react router DOM, I can see the header component output. But if I add the router, I can't see anything, the page is blank, even no errors or warnings. I tried every possible way, but it didn't work. How to solve this?

My code parts:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

```html
<Header />
    
{/* <section className='mt-24 p-8 w-full'> */}
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MainContainer />} />
        <Route path="/createItem" element={<CreateItems/> } />
    </Routes>
</Router>

{/* </section> */}
</main>
```

Comment: What is the version of React router dom you are using ?

Comment: please provide your route page full code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React Router v6, this setup should work,
try to verify if your components MainContainer and CreateItems are valid
and make sure that they are imported as well

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping all your `<Route />` components inside of a `<Switch></Switch>` instead of `<Routes></Routes>`. That should resolve the problem.

Also, I think you are using an older version of the react router so you can try upgrading to v6 as well and you will not need to wrap your routes in a `<Switch></Switch>` component either.
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5